# OnBackPressed Xamarin PCL where do i override the method

Tags: c#, xamarin, onbackpressed

I am trying to override the OnBackPressed() method in a pcl project. I do not know where i must ovveride it. In the portable project or in the android? I want to navigate to another page when i click the back button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override OnBackButtonPressed in your PCL project on your custom Page classes.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    // call your custom navigation code here

    // returning true because you are handling the navigation
    return true;
}
```

Note that this event is raised when the hardware back button is pressed but will not be raised on iOS.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.